# A phrase meaning "by now" in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech, now, should

(1) Brian said to me, "Karen should be home **by now**."

(2) Brian told me that Karen should be home **by then**.

**Question:** How would you convert (1) into a reported speech sentence?

My intuition is telling me (2) is wrong.